# Access 2010 Query Confusion

Tags: sql, ms-access

Just need some quick clarification

I have 2 Queries in my Access Database that should return Inverse results:

```
SELECT Equipment.title
FROM Equipment
WHERE (((Equipment.[EquipmentID]) Not In (

    select EquipmentID
    from DownPeriod
    where UpDate is null
)));
```

The 2nd just excludes the Not before the In.
My Confusion comes from the fact that the query posted above does not return any results if an EquipmentID field has at least 1 null value in the DownPeriod table.

It works fine if the fields are filled,  and the inverse query list always works. This makes me think there's an issue with the null value.

Now this field should never be null but I wanted to know if I could still get this to work in the unlikely event a null did occur.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: So you're querying for no-`UpDate` equipment, followed by `UpDate` equipment.. is it possible that your UpDate column is being filled with " " instead of a true NULL?

Comment: Although I can't get an example of what I'm saying, I think it may be to do with Access making a distinction between an empty string and a NULL.  Can you use Nz(UpDate,"") = "" and see if it's the same? (maybe this was corrected in 2010, as I'm sure I've seen it in 2003)

Comment: I don't think so. I took your suggestion and put the default value of Update to be Null and there was no change. As for your suggestion philly, that didn't work either but ty for the suggestion

Comment: As a thought, expand upon what phillyd said: simplify your query and note one of the rows which you know has a NULL `UpDate` field. Use the `NZ(UpDate, "THIS WAS NULL")` function in your SQL. If any rows return with "THIS WAS NULL" as their value for UpDate, you know it was properly null and that the problem lies elsewhere. If no rows contain "THIS WAS NULL", you know your field must not ACTUALLY be NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try joins:

```
SELECT Equipment.title FROM Equipment INNER JOIN DownPeriod
ON Equipment.EquipmentID = DownPeriod.EquipmentID
WHERE DownPeriod.UpDate is null
```

and

```
SELECT Equipment.title FROM Equipment INNER JOIN DownPeriod
ON Equipment.EquipmentID = DownPeriod.EquipmentID
WHERE DownPeriod.UpDate is not null
```

See if a change in syntax fixes your issue.

Not only should this work, but I believe it is a faster practise than using the `IN()` `NOT IN()` methods (might be wrong on that, but it looks nicer to read). It also adds the ability to quickly change the "is not null" criteria just the same as IN->NOT IN

Comment: Unfortunately I must be doing something off because this did not work for me either. I guess I'll just have to deal with this not being 100% fool proof. I thank you for taking the time to help tho! :)

Comment: It may lead back to `UpDate` not being a true null value, then. Try `WHERE DownPeriod.UpDate = ""` or `WHERE DownPeriod.UpDate <> ""` and see if that gives you the expected response. You may even need to combine null and "" with an OR statement; it all depends how your information is entered (for instance Excel imports often import "" as a text field instead of a real null)

Comment: Just saw something, sorry. It's not the ID which is null, it is a seperate field: the UpDate which may be null. (My impression is he has a DB of downtime, and if the UpDate is null it may mean it's not been used or is not out of the shop, etc, hence wanting to know "all new equipment" or whathaveyou based on the UpDate). In which case the where clause in your comment would not work, as the ID does exist, the UpDate does not. Also his last comment says it has not yet fixed his problem, so we will have to see. Check my last comment to the original question.

Comment: I must have glazed over that; you're right. My eyes saw "Null UpDate field" I guess. Funny how the mind works. However this SHOULD still work (using my joins above) as the ON statement ensures it shows only those fields which have a DownPeriod.EquipementID field.. I'm curious to know if this is solved and how.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with StuckAtWork's approach.  However, if you still want to understand why your original approach didn't produce the results you want, I think I can help you.

There may be an issue with empty strings which could complicate the situation.  But regardless of whether or not empty strings are involved you have something more fundamental to consider.

Here is my version of the `Equipment` table.

```
EquipmentID title
1           one
2           two
3           three
```

And here is my version of the `DownPeriod` table.

```
ID EquipmentID text_field
1  1           one
2  2           two
3              Null
4  3           three
```

I didn't include your `UpDate` field in my `DownPeriod` table.  It's irrelevant to your problem.

I pasted your SQL into a new Access query, discarded the `WHERE` clause from the subquery, and got exactly the same result as this query --- no rows returned:

```
SELECT e.title
FROM Equipment AS e
WHERE
    e.EquipmentID Not In (
        SELECT EquipmentID
        FROM DownPeriod
        );
```

So consider this situation from the db engine's perspective.  Using my version of the `Downloads` table, it has a set of values (1, 2, Null, and 3) from the subquery.  You're asking it to show you the rows from `Equipment` where `EquipmentID` is **NOT IN** that list of values.  The db engine will only give you the rows for which that condition is `True`.

`Null` is the problem.  For each `EquipmentID`, when it considers whether that value is *not* present in the subquery set, it doesn't know.  That `Null` is an unknown value ... and the unknown value might be the same as the current `EquipmentID` it's considering ... or might be something else.  But since the db engine doesn't know the real value, it can't evaluate the condition as `True`, so will not include that row in the result set.  The same thing happens for every row in `Equipment` table ... therefore your query's result set is empty (no rows).

You could get your desired results by excluding `Null` values from the subquery result set with a `WHERE` clause like the one below.  But I think StuckAtWork's suggestion is a better way to go.

```
SELECT e.title
FROM Equipment AS e
WHERE
    e.EquipmentID Not In (
        SELECT EquipmentID
        FROM DownPeriod
        WHERE EquipmentID Is Not Null
        );
```

Comment: Haha no worries I appreciate the explanation. I knew it was something to do with the NULL, and that it was screwing with filter. I think I'm going to use a dummy date like 02/01/1660 as a default value that i can check easier than null.

Comment: Agreed with HansUp, don't use dummy values. Null and Empty values exist for a reason. It may not affect you now, but later endeavours will require constant work-arounds for your dummy values. Picture sometime searching for dates between X and Y, or perhaps before Z; your dummy values will appear even though they may not be applicable. Null values will not register in such math and will be avoided by SQL (which is what you'd want)

Comment: @StuckAtWork  Well said.  He should also think about the wisdom of complicating something which would otherwise be as simple as `Min(date_field)`

Comment: That was an extremely important point that I forgot, haha thankyou!